# Can I target all <H> tags with a single selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'd like to target all h tags on a page. I know you can do it this way...

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font: 32px/42px trajan-pro-1,trajan-pro-2;
}
```

but is there a more efficient way of doing this using advanced CSS selectors? e.g something like:

```
[att^=h] {
  font: 32px/42px trajan-pro-1,trajan-pro-2;
}
```

(but obviously this doesn't work)

Comment: This becomes increasingly tedious when selecting `h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover, h4 a:hover, ...`

Comment: Yeah, would be nice to have something like: `[tag=h\d] { color: red; }`... But no, `h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { color: red; }` is all we can do still in 2022.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The new [`:is()` CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) can do it in one selector.

For example, here's how you could target all headings inside a container element:

```
:is(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) {
    color: red;
}
```

Most browsers now support `:is()`, but keep in mind that most browsers made before 2020 didn't support it without a prefix, so be careful about using this if you need to support older browsers.

In some cases, you may instead want to use the [`:where()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where) pseudo-class, which is very similar to `:is()` but has different specificity rules.

Comment: To clarify, there is no point in using `:is()` like this though. Use it when you need to match a bunch of possible values to another like `:is(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) p.subby {}`

Comment: Indeed it's pretty pointless unless you're formatting code with one selector per line and want to save some space.

Comment: This is actually very useful when using nested rules in a preprocessor like LESS or SCSS and could drastically reduce the amount of CSS by preventing cartesian products of nested rules from being generated. https://i.imgur.com/gnYR2cH.png

Comment: This answer is partially wrong. The selector doesn't target all the heading elements, just the ones inside `.container`.  Which is not what asked: Target all the heading elements inside a *page*

Comment: @MattiaAstorino it says exactly what it does. And also originally it didn't add the container class, but then using :is makes no sense (as was pointed out in some comments).

Comment: Removed the `.container` again, it is not needed and not in the original question.

Answer (score 167):

No, a comma-separated list is what you want in this case.

Comment: For those landing here from google, and wondering what a _comma-separated list_ means in CSS, it's the first example OP gave. That is, `h1, h2, h3 {}`.

Comment: This can result in a lot of duplication when it occurs in the middle of a long selector. @silverwind's answer above, recommending the use of `:is()`, allows keeping such instances DRY.

Answer (score 66):

If you're using SASS you could also use this mixin:

```
@mixin headings {
    h1, h2, h3,
    h4, h5, h6 {
        @content;
    }
}
```

Use it like so:

```
@include headings {
    font: 32px/42px trajan-pro-1, trajan-pro-2;
}
```

---

**Edit:** My personal favourite way of doing this by optionally extending a placeholder selector on each of the heading elements.

```
h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6 {
    @extend %headings !optional;
}
```

Then I can target all headings like I would target any single class, for example:

```
.element > %headings {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: It's a very small step from SCSS to SCSS+Compass: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/selectors/ -- headings($from, $to)

Comment: Wow, came across this two years later.. and the edit looks golden! I'm sure sure I understand the purpose of the `!optional` flag on the extend though? And can't seem to find anything on google...

Comment: fwiw i was researching if this can be done with styled-components

Comment: @Bill The `!optional` simply ensures that if you never use it, you don't get an error. SASS will complain if you try to extend a non-existent selector. The way it's used here, you'll probably put the first block of code (w/ h1, h2, etc.) at the top or you stylesheet or in some utility partial file, and then just use `%headings` wherever you need to. If for some reason you never actually need to modify your headings and don't use it, you'd normally get an error for trying to extend something that doesn't exist, but the optional flag silences that error by just ignoring the `@extend` completely.

Answer (score 46):

It's not basic css, but if you're using LESS (http://lesscss.org), you can do this using recursion:

```
.hClass (@index) when (@index > 0) {
    h@{index} {
        font: 32px/42px trajan-pro-1,trajan-pro-2;
    }
    .hClass(@index - 1);
}
.hClass(6);
```

Sass (http://sass-lang.com) will allow you to manage this, but won't allow recursion; they have `@for` syntax for these instances:

```
@for $index from 1 through 6 {
  h#{$index}{
    font: 32px/42px trajan-pro-1,trajan-pro-2;
  }
}
```

If you're not using a dynamic language that compiles to CSS like LESS or Sass, you should definitely check out one of these options. They can really simplify and make more dynamic your CSS development.

Comment: i am pretty sure manually typing out than creating for loop in CSS  like h1,h2,h3... takes less time, space.. more clear to understand now and later on.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯   `"can" != "should"`. Even so, the Sass/LESS options give you extensibility that vanilla CSS does not. Think of something like `font-size: (48px / @index)`.

Comment: That's ok if it best fits your needs. As mentioned in an earlier comment, if you for some reason need to operate on the index in LESS or Sass, this approach allows you to do so easily. Your implementation can be dynamic based on the header number.

Comment: For people who don't want to integrate `scss/sass` in their project, but want to generate `css` with `scss/sass` they can use this online tool called [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/)

Answer (score 14):

### Here is my attempt to solve this problem with (modern) CSS only.

Context : Inside of Joplin (very nice note taking app, [link](https://joplinapp.org/)), there is an `userfile.css` in which you can write your custom CSS for display and export of markdown notes.

I wanted to target all **headings** *directly after* (adjacent sibling) certain tags, namely `p`, `ul`, `ol` and `nav` to add a margin in between. Thus :

```
p + h1,
p + h2,
p + h3,
p + h4,
p + h5,
p + h6,
ul + h1,
ul + h2,
ul + h3,
ul + h4,
ul + h5,
ul + h6,
ol + h1,
ol + h2,
ol + h3,
ol + h4,
ol + h5,
ol + h6,
nav + h1,
nav + h2,
nav + h3,
nav + h4,
nav + h5,
nav + h6  {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

*WOW. Very long. Such selectors.*

I then came here, learnt, and tried :

```
p   + :is(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6),
ul  + :is(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6),
ol  + :is(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6),
nav + :is(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

*Hmm. Much shorter. Nice.*

And then, it struck me :

```
:is(p, ul, ol, nav) + :is(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

*Yay, this also works! How amazoomble!*

This might also work with `:where()` or other CSS combinators like `~` or even   (space) to create "matrix" of CSS selectors instead of very long lists.

Credits : all the answers on this page referencing the `:is()` selector.

Answer (score 6):

SCSS+Compass makes this a snap, since we're talking about pre-processors.

```
#{headings(1,5)} {
    //definitions
  }
```

[You can learn about all the Compass helper selectors here](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/selectors/):

Answer (score 6):

### July 2022 update

The future came and the `:is` selector is what you're looking for as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62396051/712334) given in 2020 by @silverwind (now the selected answer).

### Original answer

To tackle this with vanilla CSS look for patterns in the ancestors of the `h1..h6` elements:

```
<section class="row">
  <header>
    <h1>AMD RX Series</h1>
    <small>These come in different brands and types</small>
  </header>
</header>

<div class="row">
  <h3>Sapphire RX460 OC 2/4GB</h3>
  <small>Available in 2GB and 4GB models</small>
</div>
```

If you can spot patterns you may be able to write a selector which targets what you want. Given the above example all `h1..h6` elements may be targeted by combining the [`:first-child`](http://devdocs.io/css/:first-child) and [`:not`](http://devdocs.io/css/:not) pseudo-classes from CSS3, available in all modern browsers, like so:

```
.row :first-child:not(header) { /* ... */ }
```

In the future advanced pseudo-class selectors like [`:has()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational), and [subsequent-sibling combinators](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#general-sibling-combinators) (`~`), will provide even more control as Web standards continue to evolve over time.

Answer (score 6):

### Plain CSS

With plain css you have two ways. This targets all the heading elements wherever they are inside the page (as asked).

```
:is(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) {}
```

This one does the same but keeps the specificity to 0.

```
:where(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) {}
```

### With PostCSS

You can also use PostCSS and the [custom selectors plugin](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-custom-selectors)

```
@custom-selector :--headings h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6;

:--headings {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The jQuery selector for all h tags (h1, h2 etc) is " :header ".   For example, if you wanted to make all h tags red in color with jQuery, use:

```js
$(':header').css("color","red")
```

Comment: can you target all headings within a specific div only? eg `$('.my_div :header').css("color","red")`?

Answer (score 5):

## [Stylus](https://learnboost.github.io/stylus)'s [selector interpolation](https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/interpolation.html#selector-interpolation)

```
for n in 1..6
  h{n}
    font: 32px/42px trajan-pro-1,trajan-pro-2;
```

Comment: This does not work. Please test your code before posting an answer as this is detrimental to anyone who may try using it.

I edited your answer with tested and working code.

Comment: @Hybridwebdev It seems to be [working](http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=for%20n%20in%201..6%0A%20%20h%7Bn%7D%0A%20%20%20%20font%3A%20arial) for me. It's also how the docs describe [iteration](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/iteration.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could .class all the headings in Your document if You would like to target them with a single selector, as follows,

```
<h1 class="heading">...heading text...</h1>
<h2 class="heading">...heading text...</h2>
```

and in the css

```
.heading{
    color: #Dad;
    background-color: #DadDad;
}
```

I am not saying this is always best practice, but it can be useful, and for targeting syntax, easier in many ways,

so if You give all h1 through h6 the same .heading class in the html, then You can modify them for any html docs that utilize that css sheet.

upside, more global control versus "section div article h1, etc{}",

downside, instead of calling all the selectors in on place in the css, You will have much more typing in the html, yet I find that having a class in the html to target all headings can be beneficial, just be careful of precedence in the css, because conflicts could arise from

Answer (score 0):

Using **scss** you can [loop](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for) through 6 and [append](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/list#append) to an empty variable `$headings` using a comma separator

```
$headings: ();

@for $index from 1 through 6 {
  $headings: list.append($headings, h#{$index}, $separator: comma);
}

#{$headings} {
  --default: var(--dark);
  color: var(--default);
}
```

Thanks @steve

Answer (score 0):

Try
:is(h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) + :is(h2, h3, h4, h5, h6)