# CSS: target misc html elements inside same element

Tags: css

Is it possible to sinthesize this css code...

```
#myId p, #myId h1, #myId h2, #myId h3, #myId h4, #myId h5, #myId h6, {}
```

... into one simple rule? I'm scratching my head on this one... :P

Thanx

Pedro

Comment: use single class and used it

Comment: Besides that - any other way?

Comment: Use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), it gives you a lot of power

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do with the elements, need a bit more context before being able to help.

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539125/css-target-all-h-tags)

Comment: I want to target all text elements only.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a rule to affect ALL successors of `#myId`? Then this should work for you:

```
#myId * {}
```

Comment: I want to target all text elements ONLY.

Comment: Without any compilers (Sass, LESS), an explicit list of selectors is the only way out.

Answer (score 1):

If those are the only elements within your `#myId` container you can use:

```
#myId * { }
```

If not, then you can't really do anything like that without changing your markup (adding classes, wrapping them in containers, etc.). `p` and `h1...h6` elements are individual elements and are not stylistically related. From a stylesheet perspective the `p` tag is to a `h3` tag what an `img` tag is to a `small` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your rule through [Factor CSS](http://zamez.org/factorcss), this is what came out as the result:

```
#myId h1, #myId h2, #myId h3, #myId h4, #myId h5, #myId h6, #myId p {}
```

So unless you need a rule that affects all successors of `#myId`, I think you're out of luck.

The only other way which might be shorter, but only if you want to **not target one specific element** inside `#myId` could be `#myid :not(img) {}`.

Comment: I want to target all text elements ONLY.

Comment: Yes, CSS doesn't select based on what kind of element it is, it doesn't distinguish between them.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already you can use the wildcard selector to match any element, so `#myId *' will match all elements inside`#myId`.  If you only want to match immediate children then use the immediate child selector:

```
#myId > *
```

If you want to select a smaller list of descendants, you may want to investigate http://lesscss.org/.  This allows you to nest styles, like so:

```
#myId {
    // #myId styles here
    p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        // Some more styles here
    }
}
```

Obviously you are still having to specify each child element, but it allows you to change the parent selector once rather than for every child element.  This compiles to the same selector you started with:

```
#myId p, #myId h1, #myId h2, #myId h3, #myId h4, #myId h5, #myId h6, {}
```