# Using less to target all h tags

Tags: css, less

[Using the SASS solution as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21622588/950931), how do you do this using LESS?

```
h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6 {
    @extend %headings !optional;
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
.element > %headings {
    color: red;
}
```

Ultimately I'd want to do this in the future:

```
.something {
    %headings { color: red; }
}
```

So that it would compile to:

```
.something h1,
.something h2,
.something h3 { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like in the linked answer, there're plenty of ways (e.g. using `extend`, loops, `parent selector` or unnamed rulesets).

For your last snippet the best fit would be a mixin with [ruleset as parameter](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) (aka unnamed/detached ruleset):

```
// define:
.headings(@style) {
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        @style();
    }  
}

// use:
.something {
    .headings({
        color: red;
    });
}
```