# Trouble fetching the content of different "h" tags using selector

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I'm trying to get different titles out of multiple `h` tags from some html elements. The `h` tags always have some numbers attached to them, as in `h1`,`h14`,`h17`. I know I can make use of `.select("h1,h11,h9")` to fetch them but they are numerous. I could have handled them using `.select("[class^='heading']")` if they were something like `class="heading1"`, `class="heading2"`, `class="heading3"`.

***How can I get all the content of different `h` tags using selector?***

My attempt:

```
htmlelements="""
<h1>
    <a href="https://somesite.com/">SEC fight</a>
</h1>
<h11>
    <a href="https://somesite.com/">AFC fight</a>
</h11>
<h9>
    <a href="https://somesite.com/">UTY fight</a>
</h9>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = BeautifulSoup(htmlelements, "lxml")
for item in page.select("h11"):
    print(item.text)
```

PS regex is not an option `.find_all(string=re.compile("h"))` here.

Comment: Yikes, where does that come from? Valid HTML only goes up to `<h6>`. `<h7>`, `<h9>`, `<h11>` don’t exist. You might have to do something more or less manual (get all elements, filter by name).

Comment: No. Not for Type selection. As you have noted, you can for attributes. Type selectors must use comma separated list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539125/can-i-target-all-h-tags-with-a-single-selector

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to just use `.find_all()` for all possible `h` tags:

```
htmlelements="""
<h1>
    <a href="https://somesite.com/">SEC fight</a>
</h1>
<h11>
    <a href="https://somesite.com/">AFC fight</a>
</h11>
<h9>
    <a href="https://somesite.com/">UTY fight</a>
</h9>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = BeautifulSoup(htmlelements, "lxml")

for item in page.find_all(f"h{h}" for h in range(1, 20)):
    print(item.get_text(strip=True))
```

This would display:

```
SEC fight
AFC fight
UTY fight
```